# Finding the nearest common superclass (or superinterface) of a collection of classes

Tags: java, inheritance

Given a collection of classes, what's the best way to find the nearest common superclass?

E.g., given the following:

```
interface A {}
interface B {}
interface AB extends A, B {}
interface C {}
class AImpl implements A {}
class ABImpl implements AB {}
class ABImpl2 implements A, B {}
class BCImpl implements B, C {}
```

I would expect the following (not exhaustive):

```
commonSuperclass(A, AImpl) == A
commonSuperclass(A, B, C) == Object or null, I'm not picky
commonSuperclass(A, AB) == A
commonSuperclass(AImpl, ABImpl) == A
commonSuperclass(ABImpl, ABImpl2) == either A or B or both, I'm not picky
commonSuperclass(AImpl, ABImpl, ABImpl2) == A
commonSuperclass(ABImpl, ABImpl2, BCImpl) == B
commonSuperclass(AImpl, ABImpl, ABImpl2, BCImpl) == Object
```

I imagine I could eventually work this out, but someone must have solved it already for things like the type inference in `Arrays.asList(...)`. Can anyone point me to an algorithm, or better yet, some existing utility code?

---

**ETA:** I know about the reflection APIs. It's the algorithm (or an implementation of such an algorithm) I'm looking for.

**ETA:** And I know it's a DAG. Thank you. You're very clever.

---

**ETA:** On topological sorting (in re [EJP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9797498/27358)): the topological sort algorithms I'm familiar with require you to either:

1. start from "root" nodes `n` with no incoming edges (i.e., in this scenario, presumably `Object` and all interfaces without superinterfaces -- which one would have to examine the whole set, plus all superclasses/superinterfaces, to collect) and process all edges `(n, m)` (i.e., all `m extends/implements n`, information which again one would have to examine the whole set to collect), or
2. start from "leaf" nodes `m` with no outgoing edges (i.e., in this scenario, all classes/interfaces `m` for which no class `k extends/implements m` exists, which again one would have to examine the whole set to collect) and process all edges `(n, m)` (i.e., all class/interfaces `m` extends/implements -- which information we do have).

It's possible one or the other of these multi-pass algorithms (okay, presumably #2) is the most efficient way to do this, but it's certainly not trivially obvious. It's also entirely possible there's a one-pass topological sort algorithm I'm not familiar with, or that I've simply got these algorithms wrong, but in that case, again, "it's basically a kind of topological sort" does not immediately lead one to the answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Full working solution to best of my knowledge

- BFS of each class hierarchy going "upwards" - result into LinkedHashSet (preserve order + no duplicates)
- Intersect each set with the next to find anything in common, again LinkedHashSet to preserve order
- The remaining "ordered" set is the common ancestors, first in list is "nearest", last is furthest.
- Empty list implies no ancestors (apart from object)

Code

```
private static Set<Class<?>> getClassesBfs(Class<?> clazz) {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new LinkedHashSet<Class<?>>();
    Set<Class<?>> nextLevel = new LinkedHashSet<Class<?>>();
    nextLevel.add(clazz);
    do {
        classes.addAll(nextLevel);
        Set<Class<?>> thisLevel = new LinkedHashSet<Class<?>>(nextLevel);
        nextLevel.clear();
        for (Class<?> each : thisLevel) {
            Class<?> superClass = each.getSuperclass();
            if (superClass != null && superClass != Object.class) {
                nextLevel.add(superClass);
            }
            for (Class<?> eachInt : each.getInterfaces()) {
                nextLevel.add(eachInt);
            }
        }
    } while (!nextLevel.isEmpty());
    return classes;
}

private static List<Class<?>> commonSuperClass(Class<?>... classes) {
    // start off with set from first hierarchy
    Set<Class<?>> rollingIntersect = new LinkedHashSet<Class<?>>(
            getClassesBfs(classes[0]));
    // intersect with next
    for (int i = 1; i < classes.length; i++) {
        rollingIntersect.retainAll(getClassesBfs(classes[i]));
    }
    return new LinkedList<Class<?>>(rollingIntersect);
}
```

Supporting methods and test

```
private static void test(Class<?>... classes) {
    System.out.println("Common ancestor for "
            + simpleClassList(Arrays.asList(classes)) + ", Result =>  "
            + simpleClassList(commonSuperClass(classes)));
}

private static String simpleClassList(Collection<Class<?>> classes) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
        builder.append(clazz.getSimpleName());
        builder.append(",");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(A.class, AImpl.class);
    test(A.class, B.class, C.class);
    test(A.class, AB.class);
    test(AImpl.class, ABImpl.class);
    test(ABImpl.class, ABImpl2.class);
    test(AImpl.class, ABImpl.class, ABImpl2.class);
    test(ABImpl.class, ABImpl2.class, BCImpl.class);
    test(AImpl.class, ABImpl.class, ABImpl2.class, BCImpl.class);
    test(AB.class, ABImpl.class);
}
```

Output

```
Common ancestor for A,AImpl,, Result =>  A,
Common ancestor for A,B,C,, Result =>  
Common ancestor for A,AB,, Result =>  A,
Common ancestor for AImpl,ABImpl,, Result =>  A,
Common ancestor for ABImpl,ABImpl2,, Result =>  A,B,
Common ancestor for AImpl,ABImpl,ABImpl2,, Result =>  A,
Common ancestor for ABImpl,ABImpl2,BCImpl,, Result =>  B,
Common ancestor for AImpl,ABImpl,ABImpl2,BCImpl,, Result =>  
Common ancestor for AB,ABImpl,, Result =>  AB,A,B,
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work: given AB and ABImpl it returns A rather than AB. But on the right track.

Comment: Extra strong espresso + full rewrite, finally happy with it. Updated with tests and results. I've done it so it returns all the common ancestors, this deals with situations where there are many at same level. If you want the nearest, just pick first in the list.

Answer (score 8):

This is based on Adam's answer.

Firstly, I optimized `getClasses` so that it will create fewer temporary objects, i.e. only one `ArrayDeque` instead of a `LinkedHashSet` for each level.

```
public static Set<Class<?>> getSuperclasses(Class<?> clazz) {
    final Set<Class<?>> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    final Queue<Class<?>> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    queue.add(clazz);
    if (clazz.isInterface()) {
        queue.add(Object.class); // optional
    }
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Class<?> c = queue.remove();
        if (result.add(c)) {
            Class<?> sup = c.getSuperclass();
            if (sup != null) queue.add(sup);
            queue.addAll(Arrays.asList(c.getInterfaces()));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

To find the common superclasses, calls to `retainAll(getClasses())` can be replaced with `if (!isAssignableFrom()) remove()`, so that the quite expensive `getClasses` will be called only once. This method looks like it has worse complexity than the original solution, because of the nested loops, but that's only becaus in the original solution, the inner loop is hidden in `retainAll`.

```
public static Set<Class<?>> commonSuperclasses(Iterable<Class<?>> classes) {
    Iterator<Class<?>> it = classes.iterator();
    if (!it.hasNext()) {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
    // begin with set from first hierarchy
    Set<Class<?>> result = getSuperclasses(it.next());
    // remove non-superclasses of remaining
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Class<?> c = it.next();
        Iterator<Class<?>> resultIt = result.iterator();
        while (resultIt.hasNext()) {
            Class<?> sup = resultIt.next();
            if (!sup.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
                resultIt.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Finally, in your question it seems that you are only interested in the lowest superclass, which is why we use an ordered set. But we can also remove non-leaf classes easily. The complexity here is O(n) best-case (if there is only one result) and O(n^2) worst-case.

```
public static List<Class<?>> lowestCommonSuperclasses(Iterable<Class<?>> classes) {
    Collection<Class<?>> commonSupers = commonSuperclasses(classes);
    return lowestClasses(commonSupers);
}

public static List<Class<?>> lowestClasses(Collection<Class<?>> classes) {
    final LinkedList<Class<?>> source = new LinkedList<>(classes);
    final ArrayList<Class<?>> result = new ArrayList<>(classes.size());
    while (!source.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<Class<?>> srcIt = source.iterator();
        Class<?> c = srcIt.next();
        srcIt.remove();
        while (srcIt.hasNext()) {
            Class<?> c2 = srcIt.next();
            if (c2.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
                srcIt.remove();
            } else if (c.isAssignableFrom(c2)) {
                c = c2;
                srcIt.remove();
            }
        }
        result.add(c);
    }
    result.trimToSize();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
static <T> Class<T> commonSuperClass(Class<? extends T> c1, Class<? extends T> c2, T... args) {
    return (Class<T>)args.getClass().getComponentType();
}

static <T> Class<T> commonSuperClass(Class<? extends T> c1, Class<? extends T> c2, Class<? extends T> c3, T... args) {
    return (Class<T>)args.getClass().getComponentType();
}

static <T> Class<T> commonSuperClass(Class<? extends T> c1, Class<? extends T> c2, Class<? extends T> c3, Class<? extends T> c4, T... args) {
    return (Class<T>)args.getClass().getComponentType();
}
```

results are

```
System.out.println(commonSuperClass(A.class, AImpl.class));                                     // -> A
System.out.println(commonSuperClass(A.class, B.class, C.class));                                // -> Object
System.out.println(commonSuperClass(A.class, AB.class));                                        // -> A
System.out.println(commonSuperClass(AImpl.class, ABImpl.class));                                // -> A
System.out.println(commonSuperClass(ABImpl.class, ABImpl2.class));                              // -> A
System.out.println(commonSuperClass(AImpl.class, ABImpl.class, ABImpl2.class));                 // -> A
System.out.println(commonSuperClass(ABImpl.class, ABImpl2.class, BCImpl.class));                // -> B
System.out.println(commonSuperClass(AImpl.class, ABImpl.class, ABImpl2.class, BCImpl.class));   // -> Object
```

Comment: Interesting! However, it is not really extensible as it cannot accept a variable list of classes.

Comment: Thinking outside the box!

Answer (score 3):

For Spring Framework users there is `org.springframework.util.ClassUtils#determineCommonAncestor`.

E.g:

```
ClassUtils.determineCommonAncestor(Integer.class, LongAdder.class);
```

Comment: From looking at the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.java#L1166-L1198), I don't believe this works with interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection can give you the info you need to write your own code:

```
Class<?> c = SomeType.class; // or someObject.getClass()
Class<?> superClass = s.getSuperClass();
Class<?>[] interfaces = s.getInterfaces();
```

Comment: I would add `Class#isAssignableFrom()` to know when you've hit a common superclass/interface and it's time to traverse _down_ the class hierarchy to find the lowest common superclass/interface.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the available APIs; I was more looking for an algorithm. Or an existing utility class.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this problem right now. I only need the answer on the superclass level. Basically I found it best to only do a O(n) walk through.

You have to define an operation Cmin(A, B) giving you the nearest superclass of class A and class B.

Since Cmin results in a class itself you can use this algorithm:

Result = Cmin Ai | (ai elementIn classes).

gives you O(n).

But remember Java makes a distinction in types being interfaces or classes.